# Create a static drop down menu

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, drop-down-menu

I want to have a drop down menu which changes depending on the user's selections.

For instance:

```
let first_Field = ["-", "new recruits", "police officer", "PSO"] 
let second_field = ["-", "Training", "Courts", "Others"]
```

Third field should be based on the `first_Field` selection

```
let third_field = []
```

So i was thinking it might work with an if condition, but I don't exactly know how to do it.

For example:

```
let NR = "new recruits"
let NRtraining = ["Training1", "Training2"]

let first_Field = ["-", NR] 
let second_Field = ["training", "Tester", "School"]
if (first_Field == NR && second_Field == "training") { 
     //user selected NR and training
    //third_Field should show array of NRtraining
}
```

Help please?

Comment: Why are you comparing String With Array ?

Comment: @JatinKathrotiya it's just an example to give an idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your Data Structure Something Like :

```
   {
       "new recruits" : {
               "Training" : ["Training1", "Training2"],
               "Courts" : ["Court1","Court2"],
               "Others" : ["abc","def"]
       },
       "police officer" : {
               "Training" : ["Training1", "Training2"],
               "Courts" : ["Court1","Court2"],
               "Others" : ["abc","def"]
       },
      "PSO" : {
               "Training" : ["Training1", "Training2"],
               "Courts" : ["Court1","Court2"],
               "Others" : ["abc","def"]
       }

    }
```

on select new recruits you can change second Drop down by keys "Training, Courts, Others" and on select second  Drop down you can use value of training, courts , etc ..  for third  drop down

Swift Code :

```
      let mainDict =  [
            "new recruits" :  [
                "Training" : ["Training1", "Training2"],
                "Courts" : ["Court1","Court2"],
                "Others" : ["abc","def"]
            ],
            "police officer" : [
                "Training" : ["Training1", "Training2"],
                "Courts" : ["Court1","Court2"],
                "Others" : ["abc","def"]
            ],
            "PSO" : [
                "Training" : ["Training1", "Training2"],
                "Courts" : ["Court1","Court2"],
                "Others" : ["abc","def"]
            ]

        ]

        let firstDropArray =  ["-", "new recruits", "police officer", "PSO"]
        var second_field = ["-", "Training", "Courts", "Others"]

        // on select first Dropdown array store value of selected item here i select "new recruits"
        let firstSelect = firstDropArray[1]

        // on select second Dropdown array store value of selected item here i select "Courts"
        let seconSelect = second_field[2]

        // third array value

        let thirdArray = mainDict[firstSelect]![seconSelect]
        print(thirdArray)
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back! I'm not familiar with this, Jatin. Can you show me how to use this structure? This seems like a case to me.

Comment: i update answer with swift code example Please check